# RegExp does not match all cases

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say there is string:

```
var se = 'Trampolines rain cover';
```

and tere is search term:

```
var te = 'trampoline';
```

I have RegExp:

```
RegExp('\\b(('+te+')|('+te+')[s])\\b', 'gi');
```

It does match 'Trampolines' in the string.

**Problem:** if I look for t = 'trampoline rain'; in string with mentionet RegExp - no problems - it does match, but if I will look for **t = 'trampoline cover'** there won't be any match.

How should I edit this RegExp if it's possible to match phrases even if there are other words between them in string?

Comment: It looks like `s` and `t` need to be reversed. Also, `\b((X)|(X)[s])\b` can be simplified to `\bXs?\b`.

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question?  Don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: The question was different in previous topic, but I edited it, because I found solutions for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to do full-text search, that ain't going to work fully in JS. Take a look at http://lunrjs.com/.

But just for your usage, it may work

```
var se = 'Trampolines rain cover';
var te = 'trampoline cover';

var regexBuilder = '\\b' + te.split(/\s+/).join('s?\\b.*?\\b') + 's?\\b';
var regex = new RegExp(regexBuilder, 'gi');

se.match(regex);
```

Comment: Thanks, this what I needed. As I do my searches only in certain strings, without line breaks and other exceptions - it fits the needs.